# Frontend side of DApp

Tags: web3js, dapps, react

I am (totally new to DApp) currently involved in a research project that regarding the Front-end side (Js Libraries and Frameworks) of the DApp. I read many articles but still confused.

My question is, could help me to clarify this with e.g a graph that shows/describes the tools/technologies/libraries etc (Like HTML5, CSS, React web3, etc..) that **must** be used and the interaction between all of them ?

A simple brief/detailed documentation for each tool/technology/library would great :)

Comment: If you haven't found it already, [cryptoZombies](https://cryptozombies.io/) may be a good place to start! Depending on your background this may seem basic but it covers the essentials in a very accessible way, rather than having to read through pages and pages of documentation...

Answer (score 1):

I start to build dApps a month ago and I have a problem with examples and difficulties to start.

Here are the resources that help me to start.
https://coursetro.com/posts/code/99/Interacting-with-a-Smart-Contract-through-Web3.js-(Tutorial) - Very useful to start.
You need to decide which version of web3 to use 0.2 or 1.0:
https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API
I advise you to start with 0.2 because the metamask use this version and more of examples are built on this version.

See some dApp example on Github.
You can check my school project here: https://github.com/ivan3a/DecentralizedCarLog

You need to master web3 and how to interact with contracts. After that will be easy.